Displaying Form Data with Dynamic Field Types Using Filament's Form Repeater in Laravel
I am currently working on a web-based form application using Laravel 10 and Filament PHP. I have a form table with columns containing data as follows:
[
    {
        "value": "John Doe",
        "desc": "Full Name",
        "type": "string",
        "valid": false
    },
    {
        "value": "Elm Street No. 13",
        "desc": "Address",
        "type": "text",
        "valid": false
    },
    {
        "value": "0142365789",
        "desc": "Phone Number",
        "type": "string",
        "valid": false
    }
]

Now, I want to display this data using the Form Repeater provided by Filament. Below is a snippet of my code:
Step::make('Form')
    ->description('Form submission')
    ->schema([
        Forms\Components\Repeater::make('form')->schema(function (Get $get): array {
            switch ($get('type')) {
                case 'string':
                    $formField = TextInput::make('value');
                    break;
                case 'text':
                    $formField = Textarea::make('value');
                    break;
                case 'image':
                    $formField = SpatieMediaLibraryFileUpload::make('value')->getUploadedFiles();
                    break;
                case 'file':
                    $formField = FileUpload::make('value')->downloadable();
                    break;
                case 'date':
                    $formField = DatePicker::make('value')->displayFormat(function (): string {
                        return 'd/m/Y';
                    });
                    break;
                default:
                    $formField = TextInput::make('value');
            }
            return [
                $formField,
                Textarea::make('note'),
                Toggle::make('valid'),
            ];
        })->addable(false)
            ->deletable(false)
            ->reorderable(false)
            ->reorderableWithDragAndDrop(false)
            ->columnSpanFull(),
    ])

When I tried running the code I didn't encounter any errors at all and the data appeared by what was stored in the table until finally I realized that the data did not appear according to the type of each data. For example, if the data type is a string, a TextInput should be displayed, and if it's a file, a FileInput should be displayed. The problem is, that I'm not sure how to correctly access the data type from the form column before displaying it. When I tried adding dd($get('type)), it returns null.
Can anyone help me solve this issue? Any advice or answers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

If you could share the code with the wizard, and how exactly were the data used in the components

So you are basically using a Repeater where you should have used a Builder?
